# Python notification not working after pyinstaller

Tags: python, notifications, pyinstaller

I have a python script that sends notifications, it works fine in my ide but when I use pyinstaller to create an EXE. the script doesn't seem to work and no notification is played. There is also no errors when opening the EXE, it's just that no notification is being played. Also, when im creating the exe with pyinstaller I make sure to use --hidden-import pyler.platforms.win.notification.

```
from plyer import notification
def notifyMe(title, message):
    notification.notify(
        title = title,
        message = message,
        app_name= "Remind",
        app_icon = "clock.ico",
        timeout = 25,
    )
notifyMe("Test", "test")
```

This is the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toast notifier library instead of pyler

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

toast = ToastNotifier()
toast.show_toast("Title here", "Message here", duration=10)
```

If you want to use pyler only, then I'm pretty sure that the problem is with the app icon destination folder. Try changing it to a specific path.

Instead of `app_icon = "clock.ico"`

Write `app_icon = "C:\Users\clock.ico"`

If this doesn't work, you can also write `app_icon = "C:\\Users\\clock.ico"`

When you use Pyinstaller, the location of the python file will no longer be the same which will give an error if you don't specify the exact destination folder.

***Hope this answer helps!***